# How to configure Build.gradle file to include boofcv library in a project for android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, boofcv

i am new to android studio and wants to include boofcv library in my project. I am using Android studio for development. I have done the following steps in order to include the library and is stuck with build.gradle configuration.

Step 1: Have downloaded per-compiled jar files from http://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Download:BoofCV

Step 2: Have updated settings.gradle as

```
    include ':app'
    include ':libs:boofcv-libs'
```

Step 3: My build.gradle looks like:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    buildscript {
           repositories {
                       jcenter()
                         }
           dependencies {
                       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
                        }
                 }
   allprojects {
          repositories {
                    jcenter()
                       }
               }
   dependencies {
         compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
                 }
```

Comment: `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`
    `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'`

Comment: Add the above two lines in your dependencies.

Comment: i have just tried the thing. and the error comes to be Gradle DSL method not found; compile()

Answer (score 3):

As the note of your **project's** `build.gradle` file will suggest:

// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong

// in the individual module build.gradle files

Remove the compile statements in that gradle file:

```
 compile project(":libs:boofcv-libs")
```

And copy them to other **(module's)** `build.gradle` and make dependencies look like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
    compile project(":libs:boofcv-libs")


}
```

Answer (score 0):

BoofCV is on maven central so you could just do the following too:

```
['calibration','feature','geo','ip','recognition','sfm','android'].each
{ String a -> compile group: 'org.boofcv', name: a, version: '0.18' }
```

In the next it will be even easier if you just want everything:

```
compile group: 'org.boofcv', name: "all", version: '0.19-SNAPSHOT'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get latest version from this page
   https://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Download
2. Convert maven to to gradle using this website and make sure to
   change artifactId to boofcv-android:
   http://sagioto.github.io/maven2gradle

so it will be something like this:

```
compile "org.boofcv:boofcv-android:0.27"
```

as mentioned in [this page](https://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Android_support#Having_Trouble_in_Android_Studio.3F), to avoid library conflict add this to app.gradle:

```
// Remove libraries that conflict with libraries already included with Android
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: "xmlpull", module: "xmlpull"
    all*.exclude group: "org.apache.commons", module: "commons-compress"
}
```